# Data is not constantly loading from custom wordpress table

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, server

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename_temp = $wpdb->prefix . 'faculty_temp';
$toke = $_GET['token'];
$user = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename_temp where token='$toke'");
```

This is to fetch data from custom wordpress table, the loads fine sometimes. On some times data isn't fetched. Like I refresh 10 times, data doesn't appear in 1 out of 10 times. Seems to be server issue, while updating files in Advanced File Manager & while getting data in WP data access plugin also has same issue

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server - tag correctly!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code is unsafe. Need to add the sanitize functions and the escaping query to the database

```php
global $wpdb;
$tablename_temp = $wpdb->prefix . 'faculty_temp';
$toke = isset( $_GET['token'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['token'] ) ) : '';
$user = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename_temp where token='".$wpdb->esc_like($toke)."'");
```

The code is valid. Perhaps the problem is that you are simultaneously writing and deleting to the temporary table "faculty_temp" and the fetch request is sent when data is deleted or modified.

Need to change your method for working with temp data

Comment: I used these functions, still there's problem. But you helped indeed. Thank you

Comment: @TyphixDev can you provide additional debugging info so that it's more clear what you mean with the problem.  Since the answer that is provided here should be working.

Comment: @HowardE the code works fine, despite that sometimes $user returns an empty array. When the page is refreshed over again.

Comment: Try installing this https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ and debug your query to see if in fact it's making the right request.